# replicate observation of column for each row in another columns in r

Tags: r, database, dataframe, transform, replication

My question may be misleading but is simpler with an example :

imagine I have a dataframe of countries

```
Departure 

US
FRANCE
BRESIL
```

I want something like this :

```
Departure      Arrival

US             US
FRANCE         US
BRESIL         US
US             FRANCE
FRANCE         FRANCE
BRESIL         FRANCE
US             BRESIL
FRANCE         BRESIL
BRESIL         BRESIL
```

But I have actually way more destinations. I think there is a simple way to do it but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like

```r
expand.grid(Departure = Departure, Arrival = Departure)
```

with your data:

```r
Departure <- c("US", "FR", "BR")

expand.grid(
    Departure = Departure,
    Arrival = Departure
)
#>   Departure Arrival
#> 1        US      US
#> 2        FR      US
#> 3        BR      US
#> 4        US      FR
#> 5        FR      FR
#> 6        BR      FR
#> 7        US      BR
#> 8        FR      BR
#> 9        BR      BR
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! that is exactly what I wanted! thanks